# Android in-app purchase, getting order cancelled

Tags: android, in-app

I have integrated in app purchase into my android application. When I get to the purchase screen to select my credit card, 4111111111111111 and other test credit cards fail. So I try my real credit card. This too fails, everytime I get a "Error. Your payment could not be processed. Sign In to your Google Wallet account to request support.

Email id `x@gmail.com` is the primary account on my device (yes I am testing on a device).`x@gmail.com` is also setup as a "test account" on my play.google.com->Edit profile page. What could I be doing wrong ?

Edit : My launched application in the market does not have "BILLING" permission enabled. My new version uploaded, but not "activated" has BILLING permission. My test app and my online "latest inactive app" both are of the same version, versioncode. Also I have "published my in app unmanaged products" (since any way my live product wont have in app capability).

Yes, my public key is correctly added to my Security.java file.

Comment: please tell me if i have an inactive in app product on android market so will it be shown to user ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test account was not my primary account on my phone. I had to remove all accounts and create the test account as the primary account on my phone for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Google play merchant account is supported only in below mentioned countries. If you are residing in India and don't have a bank account in any of below mentioned countries you can't sell your paid app.

[Supported locations for merchants](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)

Comment: The issue is with the credit card that we are using, we were able to shop using a international credit card. Any reason why a test credit card wont work ?

Comment: @thavan : please tell me if i have an inactive in app product on android market so will it be shown to user ??